# Beamer: Ignore part of item in spacing of itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize, only

I want to make an itemization where one item is displayed in a long form when it is first uncovered, but then reduced to a short form when the subsequent items are uncovered.

With the MWE below, the other items move around, which I would like to avoid.

I heard about `\smash`, which I hoped would print the additional info in the long form without giving it a box, but it throws an error `Missing $ inserted`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Test
    \begin{equation*}
    f(y)=\sum_{m} c_{m}\phi_{m}(y),
    \end{equation*} 

    \item<2-> Test
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2->  Test%This item has a long and short form
        \begin{onlyenv}<2>
                :\begin{equation*}c_{m}\approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(y_i)\phi_{m}(y_i)\end{equation*}
        \end{onlyenv}
        \item<3-> Test
    \end{itemize}

    \item<4-> Test
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<4-> Test
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the following fully automatic solution. It behaves exactly like one would expect (I hope): Use

```
\shortlongitem{slide_number}{short_text}{expansion_set_after_short_text}
```

where `slide_number` is a **single number**, e.g. `2`, it won't work with any addition like `2-`. `short_text` is displayed all the time starting from `slide_number` (beamer: `<slide_number->`). `expansion_set_after_short_text` is set after `short_text`, visible only in `slide_number`, not shifting anything, not taking any space.

Sadly I couldn't use the `\newcommand<>` from `beamer` (hence not using the same syntax for slide-aware commands), because I needed to modify the slide number (see the special counter) to not print `short_text` twice on the same position. This would make it look strange on screens which is the intended use of presentations.

The command (has to be put in preamble):

```
\newcounter{slitem}
\newcommand{\shortlongitem}[3]{%
\setcounter{slitem}{#1}%
\item<\theslitem->%
\only<\theslitem>{%
    \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \rlap{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#2#3}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\stepcounter{slitem}%
\visible<\theslitem->{#2}%
}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\newcounter{slitem}
\newcommand{\shortlongitem}[3]{%
\setcounter{slitem}{#1}%
\item<\theslitem->%
\only<\theslitem>{%
    \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
        \rlap{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#2#3}%
        }%
    }%
}%
\stepcounter{slitem}%
\visible<\theslitem->{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Test
    \begin{equation*}
    f(y)=\sum_{m} c_{m}\phi_{m}(y),
    \end{equation*} 

    \item<2-> Test
    \begin{itemize}
        \shortlongitem{2}{Test}{ with a long long long long long line that breaks somewhere : \begin{equation*}
                                    c_{m}\approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(y_i)\phi_{m}(y_i)
                                    \end{equation*}}
        \item<3-> Test
    \end{itemize}

    \item<4-> Test
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<5-> Test
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```